# ( React-Native ) Detecting when an action dispatched a result or payload in component level

Tags: react-native

I am trying to load a list of data from an API call by an action defined like this:

```
export const searchForTrips = (searchParams) => {
let url = 'http://..............com/ferry/public/api/trip/search';
url = bindParamsToUrl(url, searchParams);
return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({ type: AVAILABLE_TRIPS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
        });
    };
 };
```

I am receiving the dispatch by a reducer and passing the payloads to component level props. When I make the action call in the ComponentDidMount method, the action returns null data. How to detect if the action is actually dispatched the payload or not from component?

Comment: `componentDidMount` is called when the component is mounted, you can  call another hook i.e [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action), and check the data there.

Comment: I had a bit of googling about it and found out that [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) is not preferrable compared to [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). However, thanks for the idea though!

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` will be deprecated in `React 17`, therefore try avoiding it as much as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) to receive the props when the props update is occurred and rendering the view according to the props.